# Monitoring the System Log File via Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, logging, system

I am currently using the following to read the system log:

```
journalctl -u <service name> | tail -n1
```

However I have a need to monitor the system log live, as changes come in (in a bash script), instead of just looping through the log file.

What is the best way to do this? I did some research to where the journalctl command is reading from, and it seems that the system logs are unreadable (or at least when I attempted with cat.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`journalctl` tool has a `-f` flag which enables printing the contents of log file as soon as it is changed. Use it like this:

`$ journalctl -u <service name> -f`

Comment: Thanks! Will this work in a script though? I imagine that I would need some way of constantly reading that input. That is where I am stuck

I have iterated a loop so far with a sleep, but this is not catching every new line.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "work in a script"? You can use it like this:

`$ journalctl -u <service> -f | grep <whatever you want to grep>` and grep will work on each appended line in your log file

Comment: For clarity, my end goal is to continually read the entries from the system log file, process them through a loop, and continue to do so until the script is terminated.   

So I would need to do something like 

`<journalctl -u <service name> -f | grep <details>  
read <input from above>    
case...`

Comment: I believe it can work for you like this, for example:

`journalctl -u <service name> -f | grep <details> | ./process-through-loop.sh`

Comment: That makes sense, however I believe my requirements include this logic being inside of the script, instead of running it from a journal command. If I was to go with your suggested route, would I just use a `while read line` to iterate through each incoming line? Do you have any idea if I could implement the function of doing a journalctl -f inside a bash script?